# Google Analytics 4, I am receiving "(other)" as user's language - when I migrate from Universal Analytics to Google Analytics 4

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-4, universal-analytics

I use these codes to set the visitor's language:

```
gtag('set', 'language', 'client language');
```

also, when I want to trigger the "page_view" event, I set the visitor's language like this too:

```
gtag('event', 'page_view', {
    page_title: 'PAGE TITLE',
    page_path: 'PAGE PATH',
    page_location: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname,
    language: 'client language',
});
```

these codes were working as I expect on Universal Analytics, you can see the screenshot:
[image]

but the same code on the same page, only shows the "(other)" as the visitor's language when I use Google Analytics 4:
[image]

what may cause this problem?
how can I set the visitor's language by coding on Google Analytics 4?

I thought maybe the problem was caused by not having standard names for my languages so I tried to use ISO 639 language codes but it doesn't solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the documentation [Automatically collected events](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9234069).
The following parameters are collected by default with every event, including custom events. The automatically collected events that don't have parameters listed in the table below only receive the following parameters:

> language
>
> page_location
>
> page_referrer
>
> page_title
>
> screen_resolution

so you do not need to write any code. Probably, what you have written is overwriting on the value of language.

For the Page-View, that would be automatically collected, if you turn on `Advance Measurement`.

Therefore, I recommend to delete the extra codes.
[image: Advance Measurement]

Comment: Hi Shila,  
thanks for your answer.   
I am using Google Analytics on a virtual tour, so when the user changes the scene, I have to trigger the "page_view" event manually.  
also, when the user changes the language in the virtual tour, I need to have the user's behavior in that language on Google Analytics. so the browser language is not important to me and I have to set the active language based on the user's choice for Google Analytics manually too!  
Thanks,  
Hamid

Comment: Do you mean that the page-view and language you search for, are different from what GA4 automatically collects? If yes, you should define custom events or custom dimensions and in case GA4 does not have a pre-defined function to set the value, you need to set them by javascript